# Torus as union of circles

Tags: general-topology

How do I show that the solide torus can be view as the union of circles?
I know that the solid torus can be view as $D^2\times S^1$, but, how do I can show that this construction is equivalent to the union of circles?

Comment: Is it not the union $\bigcup_{x\in D^2} x\times S^1$?

Comment: What do you mean is "equivalent" to the union of circles? There are a lot of things you can write as a union of circles. If you know the solid torus is $D^2 \times S^1$, then you can write it as the union over $\{x\} \times S^1$...

Comment: What Quang Hoang says. Alternatively you can write $D^2\setminus\{*\}$ as a union of circles, have a copy of those circles for all the points of $S^1$, and then have $\{*\}\times S^1$ remaining. Or use something like a Hopf fibration.

Comment: thanks everyone, now I see. I am sorry.

Comment: yes, @Mike, thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I was expecting something like this.

Comment: @Jyrki: Well, that's evil, since what you described is not a foliation. "Something like the Hopf fibration" doesn't make sense, since you'll just recover the foliation we've been talking about in the comments. A "twisty" way to do this is to take the quotient under $z \mapsto z^n$ in the first coordiante; then we have the center circle is a leaf, and the others wrap around the center circle $n$ times. Indeed these together form the local picture of a 3-manifold foliated by circles (aka a Seifert fibered space).

Comment: @MikeMiller: I was thinking about writing all those copies of $S^1\times S^1$ as unions of circles wrapping once around each hole (type (1,1) if you like). That's what I had in mind when I talked about Hopf fibration. So yet another alternative. True, the center core would still need to be dealt with separately, so talkiing about Hopf was misleading.